# Check if all records returned have same column value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following query:

```
ManifestImage::whereBetween('created_at', [$img->created_at, $fewseconds])->whereNull('original_pdf')->get();
```

This works well to get the correct records I need, but I want to go one step further. At the moment here is an example return:

`[{"id":404,"manifest_id":3601,"name":"3601_1559451552023428000.jpeg","mime":"image\/jpeg","type":"jpeg","created_at":"2019-06-01 22:59:12","updated_at":"2019-11-11 14:47:08","original_pdf":null,"image_type":2,"temp_group":null},
{"id":405,"manifest_id":3601,"name":"3601_1559451552068266200.jpeg","mime":"image\/jpeg","type":"jpeg","created_at":"2019-06-01 22:59:12","updated_at":"2019-11-11 14:47:08","original_pdf":null,"image_type":2,"temp_group":null},{"id":406,"manifest_id":3601,"name":"3601_1559451553041321000.jpeg","mime":"image\/jpeg","type":"jpeg","created_at":"2019-06-01 22:59:13","updated_at":"2019-11-11 14:47:08","original_pdf":null,"image_type":2,"temp_group":null}]`

What I would like to be able to check is if all of the above records returned have just one value for `manifest_id`. All of these have the value of 3601, so what I'd like to do is pass through a conditional statement where if there is only one unique number out of this set, move on to the next step, otherwise skip it entirely.

Comment: Did you try to use ->groupBy('manifest_id') ?

Comment: group by won't work because you cannot get specific values for other fields... BTW, simple loop through result collection will work and this is a good brute force solution...

Comment: or subquery / two-query solution: select count(manifest_id) from "ManifestImage table" where id in ("id list from previous query")

Comment: There is no need to add `Thanks for all assistance` (or similar) to the footer of all of your questions. You've probably had ~100 removed by now. Remember that the editors that try to keep this place tidy are volunteers. We may be foolish for taking on the task, but we believe in this community, for all its many faults. We would rather not have to clean up after users who add redundant and conversational material wilfully.